# Return multiple values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

This is a homework problem.  I need to write a function called 'allBy' that takes (artist) as an argument.
When run, this function should return an array of all records in "collection" that are by the given artist.

I've written a function that will return only one record, but not multiple.

The console logs are a function that adds a record to the collection.

```
 let collection = [];

 function addToCollection( title, artist, year) {
   collection.push({title, artist, year}); // adds album to array
   return {title, artist, year};  // returns newly created object
 } // end of addToCollection function     


 console.log( addToCollection('The Real Thing', 'Faith No More', 
 1989));
 console.log( addToCollection('Angel Dust', 'Faith No More', 
 1992));
 console.log( addToCollection( 'Nevermind', 'Nirvana', 1991));
 console.log( addToCollection( 'Vulgar Display of Power', 
 'Pantera', 1991));

 function allBy(artist) {
   for ( let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
   // for ( disc of collection) {
       if (collection[i].artist === artist) {
         return [collection[i].title];
       }
     }
 }
```

I want to get all records by the given artist in the form of an array, but I'm only able to get one.  Am I even close on this?

Comment: You're using `return` inside your loop, which stops all operations in your function. once you meet your `collection[i].artist === artist` the first time, your function stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main function, `allBy()`, returns as soon as it sees the first matching artist. Try declaring an empty array and storing the matches you find in it so you can return the array outside the loop.

```
function allBy(artist) {

   var matches = []; // create an empty array to store our matches

   for ( let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
       // console.log('current collection item: ', collection[i]); // optional: log or add a breakpoint here to understand what's happening on each iteration
       if (collection[i].artist === artist) {
         matches.push(collection[i].title); // add a match we've found
         // return [collection[i].title];
       }
   }

   return matches; // tada!
 }
```

Comment: Wow that worked great!  Thanks so much for the help!!  Can you explain the logic of the if statement for me?  I'm still pretty new to JS.  So when it finds a match, it adds it to the title property of my array (collection[i].title)?

Comment: @JamesPaulMolnar Glad to help! Not sure if you're asking in general about conditionals, the `if` condition here is from your code.

Comment: @JamesPaulMolnar I updated my answer to hint where you might add debugging. The `if(collection[i].artist === artist)` condition is seeing if the artist of the collection I'm looking at right now is an exact match to the I'm looking for. If it is, I add the **title** of the current collection item to my result. If that's not what you want returned, I suggest playing with it a bit more and debugging but you're close. :)

Comment: That is exactly what I want to be returned.  The code works beautifully now.  I am just trying to understand the logic.  I understand that if the conditional is true, then it executes the next line of code.  So how is it that the function knows to push the title from that particular artist in the collection?  Does the [ i ] variable save the artist info from the conditional statement?  I thought that the "if" conditional was only meant to be true or false.  So why doesn't the next line of code push all titles[ i ] to matches?  Please forgive me if I am making this difficult!

Comment: `i` is an index. For a simple array ['apple', 'banana','orange'], 'apple' is at index 0, 'banana' at 1, and 'orange' at 2. The source array contains collections (items with a title, author, year) and the output array contains only titles.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `map` with `filter`:

```
function allBy(artist) {
    return collection.filter(({ artist: a }) => a == artist).map(({ title }) => title);
}
```